Dialog page cannot be rendered successfully
I'm trying to navigate to page on my application on page load with this code below
apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=110:25', {
    title: "Interactive Report",
    modal: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});

But I'm getting Application 110 Dialog page 25 cannot be rendered successfully. Ensure the page template in use on page 25 is of template type "Dialog page", with appropriate JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog cancel code defined. what could be the possible solutions to it?

did you already follow the suggestion given: Ensure the page template in use on page 25 is of template type "Dialog page", with appropriate JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog cancel code defined ?

I have followed the suggestions but I'm getting the same error message

This is a very vague question, so I'm assuming the following. User accesses a page and a dialog page immediately opens. In APEX a dialog is just a type of page that can be accessed using a redirect.
Test case:
Form and Report
Create and interactive report with form on table EMP using the create page wizard. This will generate a report with and edit icon for each row and a "Create" button to open the form. In my testcase the report is page 254 and the form is page 256. Page 256 is of type "Modal"
Page item to hold url of the form page.

On page 254, create a page item P254_CREATE_URL of type Hidden
Create a before header computation on item P254_CREATE_URL of type Expression > PL/SQL with source:

APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page   => 256)

This will ensure that the url of the form is stored in the page item when the page is rendered. This syntax also ensures checksum is included. Page 256 is defined as a modal page and this url will take that into account.
Dynamic action

Create a dynamic action on event: Page Load
Add an action of type Execute Javascript Code with the following source:

apex.navigation.redirect ( "&P254_CREATE_URL." );

Run the page and observe the report is renders and the form is opened immediately as a dialog.
